# How to Install package manager (PKG) on a freeBSD release version

Tags: port, freebsd, package-management

I wanted to try out FreeBSD from a live image (on a USB stick) before I installed it. I thought of installing Neofetch to check the system specs. It is a release version but it didn't have the package manager `pkg` (I found that weird coming from Linux background). It said:

> A pre-built version of 'pkg' could not be found for your system. Consider changing PACKAGEFILE or installing it from ports : :ports-mgmt/pkg'

This is where I get stuck. I downloaded the .xz file, which is the repository where I thought the PKG source is. Am I correct? If not, how should I download it from the online repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are no pre-built packages

for *memstick* and *mini-memstick* images as [announced](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.2R/announce.html).

If there are no pre-built packages *ports-mgmt/pkg* is useless. You might want to use [ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html) to test the sticks. [Virtual Machine Images](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) might be more convenient for extensive  testing.